# E: Unable to locate package freelan

Tags: debian

I'm using Debian 10 (Buster) on a Raspberry Pi (as a VM) and I can't seem to download and install freelan. I performed an "apt-get update" beforehand. Just seeing if any one else has had the same issue.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package freelan
```

Comment: Actually turns out that there is a package for Debian 9 (Stretch). But not for Buster yet. Instead I downloaded the code onto Buster and compiled it there. Seems to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

So when you search for freelan  on debian website , you can see that `freelan` is not anymore in buster .

search url :

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=freelan

more information about the package :

https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/freelan